# Get the requesting URL in Callable Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a service that shares html to multiple client web sites. I need to know The URL of where the request is coming from.

The client will add a custom script to their website and the script will load Firebase SDK and call one of my callable firebase functions.

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //How do you access the requesting URL?
    console.log(context.rawRequest.originalUrl) "/"
    console.log(context.rawRequest.url) "/"
})
```

Thank you,

Comment: You'll have to pass in the URL into the cloud function by the page making the request. use ```window.location.href``` to get the page URL and load it into ```data```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP requests to callable functions don't really come "from" a URL.  They come from anywhere on the internet.  It could be a web site, Android or iOS app, or someone who simply knows the [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) to call the function.

If you're building a web app and you want to pass along the URL of the page making the request, you'll have to add that data into the object that the client passes to the function, which shows up in `data`.