# How to test App Check Functions on Firebase Emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, firebase-app-check

I can successfully enable App Check for my Firebase Functions and they are working as expected when I deploy them to the Firebase server. However, when I try to test with Firebase emulator, the functions with App Check will return unauthenticated error.

How can I make the emulator return a valid response? Is there any way like adding the debug token in the emulator, like the Firebase console?

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to turn off App Check when the functions is running on emulator. This can be achieve by checking the environment variable **FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR**.

```ts
exports.hello = functions
  .runWith({
    enforceAppCheck: process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR !== "true", 
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return "Hello";
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my undestanding base on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084447/firebase-appcheck-when-working-with-emulator-on-localhost). The use of the app check using local emulators is not possible. This is presumably because localhost is not listed as an allowed domain, resulting in unathenticated error.

A workaround was recommended on the same post. Another user successfully set up app check by adding this snippet right above the call to activate appCheck.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
}

const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
appCheck.activate(
  process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_CHECK_SITE_KEY,
  true,
);
```

Hope this will help you on your use case. for more information you can check the [orginal post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084447/firebase-appcheck-when-working-with-emulator-on-localhost).

Comment: Even though localhost should not be listed as an allowed domain, local Firebase emulator should have a way to whitelist the app, just like when we use the actual Firebase backend which accepts the debug token. The quote code above is not helpful for local Firebase emulator.